How to fix flicker in flutter web loading screen looks
When loading our flutter web url, mid way through loading, the screen flickers from what seems like a shrunken down version of the shimmer loading screen to a fuller shimmer loading screen.
I’d like to make the full image appear only. This only effects mobile web and not desktop web.
Loader.css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Centers the card horizontally and vertically */
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 100vh;
  /* Maintains full height */
  width: 100vw;
  /* Full width on mobile */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.shimmerBG {
  animation-duration: 2.2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: shimmer;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background: #ddd;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #F6F6F6 8%, #F0F0F0 18%, #F6F6F6 33%);
  background-size: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}

@keyframes shimmer {
  0% {
    background-position: -1200px 0;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 1200px 0;
  }
}

.media {
  height: 400px;
}

.p-32 {
  padding: 32px;
}

.title-line {
  height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.content-line {
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.end {
  width: 45%;
}

.m-t-24 {
  margin-top: 24px;
}

Index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta property="og:title" content="Outing - Private Group Outings">
  <meta property="og:description" content="Discover, Book, & Organize. Effortlessly.">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/53355651515_dc229c0958_o_d.png">

  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

  <!-- <meta name="description" content="Outing - Private Group Outings"> -->

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="lib">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <link rel="preload" href="loader.css" as="loader">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="loader.css">

  <title>Outing</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDLbxWMRsmaSurA-j3g3Mhw4BmgJpO__nw" async></script>

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" sizes="32x32">

  <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-analytics.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyDLbxWMRsmaSurA-j3g3Mhw4BmgJpO__nw",
      authDomain: "outing-e92a8.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "outing-e92a8",
      storageBucket: "outing-e92a8.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "702556041438",
      appId: "1:702556041438:web:99943d3c6619df24d6124f",
      measurementId: "G-SM40VHD99G"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
  </script>

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>


<body>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="shimmerBG media"></div>
    <div class="p-32">
      <div class="shimmerBG title-line"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG title-line end"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line m-t-24"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line end"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Adding more shimmer elements for a full-page effect -->
    <div class="p-32">
      <div class="shimmerBG title-line"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line end"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-32">
      <div class="shimmerBG title-line"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line end"></div>
      <div class="shimmerBG content-line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      var loader = document.getElementById('loader');
      loader.style.display = 'none'; // Hides the loader
      // Or use loader.remove(); to completely remove the element from the document
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      const darkThemeMq = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
      // TODO turned off for now while we are workign with only light mode
      // if (darkThemeMq.matches) {
      //   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style = "position: fixed; inset: 0px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; user-select: none; touch-action: none; font: 14px sans-serif; color: red; background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);";
      // } else {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style = "position: fixed; inset: 0px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; user-select: none; touch-action: none; font: 14px sans-serif; color: red; background-color: white;";
      // }

      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: async function (engineInitializer) {
          let appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine({});
          let loaderElement = document.getElementById('loader');
          if (loaderElement) {
            loaderElement.remove();
          }
          await appRunner.runApp();
        }
      });
    });

  </script>

  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" async></script>

</body>

</html>


I tried changing the viewport settings and adjusting the size from percentages to fixed values but didn’t really notice a change in the flicker from smaller version of the shimmer to the larger

Did the flicker happen after you added :animation-name: shimmer;  It lasts for 2 seconds .. perhaps the time you are talking about where the flicker happens?
